# Result of Onkeyup/KeyDown with Loadmore onPage scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making onkeyup search the items.
Onkeyup search result part works fine but I want to put the result of onkeyup search as Load more on page scroll.

I have the code for page scroll also but it is not working.

What i have noticed it is not passing the page numbers.

Or any possibility to mixup the keyup and loadmore code into one?

Any helpwould be highly appreciated. Thanks

**index.php**

```
<form name="keyup">
    <input value="" type="text" id="book" >
</form>

<div id="comboB" class="comboB products-container" style="z-index: -999999999999999;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#book').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.comboB').load('search.php ', {action: 'onkeyup',  textboxSearch: $(this).val()
},
{action: 'onkeydown',  textboxSearch: $(this).val()}, function(response) {
        console.log('Response of sample: ' + response + ' if you need');
});

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        var total_pages = parseInt($("#total_pages").val());
        var page = parseInt($("#page").val())+1;
        if(page <= total_pages) {
        load_more_data(page, total_pages);
        } 
    }
});

function load_more_data(page, total_pages) {
$("#total_pages, #page").remove(); 
$.ajax({
url: 'search.php',
type: "POST",
data: {page: page},
beforeSend: function(){
    $(".loader").show();
},
complete: function(){
$('.loader').hide();
    if(page == total_pages) {
    $(".loader").html('<hr style="border: 2px black solid;"><h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i> Total Results ( <font color="red">' + <?php echo $ttrows; // Category ID ?> + '</font> ) - No More Results <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i></h2><hr style="border: 2px black solid;">').show();
    }
},
success: function(data){
    $(".comboB").append(data);
},
error: function(){
$(".loader").html("No data found!");
}
});
}
</script>
```

**sample.php**

```
<?php
include('inc/db.php');

$name = $_POST['textboxSearch'];

$limit = 12;
if(isset($_POST['page']) && $_POST['page'] != "") {
    $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($dba, $_POST['page']);
    $offset = $limit * ($page-1);
} else {
    $page = 1;
    $offset = 0;
}

$mcats  =   "
SELECT * FROM items where ename like '".$name."%'
limit $offset, $limit
";

$mcattr =   "
select count(*) as total_rows from items where ename like '".$name."%'
";

$res = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($dba, $mcattr));
$total_pages = ceil($res->total_rows/$limit);

$rests = mysqli_query($dba, $mcats);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rests) > 0) {

$results = "";
$results .= '<input type="hidden" name="total_pages" id="total_pages" value="' . $total_pages . '">';
$results .= '<input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="' . $page . '">';

$mcat = $dba->query($mcats);
while ($mcatt = $mcat->fetch_assoc()){

    $id =   $mcatt['id'];
    $ename= $mcatt['ename'];
    $aname= $mcatt['aname'];
    $file=  $mcatt['filename']; 
?>
<li class="product-list-item col-md-4 col-xs-6" style="z-index: 3;">
<div class="product-entry">
<div class="product-thumbnail" oncontextmenu="return false">
<center>
<img draggable="false" (dragstart)="false;" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999999;" 
class=" unselectable retina" src="images/items/<?php echo $file; ?>" alt="food">
</div>

<div class="product-content" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999999;">
<h4 class="product-name"><?php echo $ename; ?></h4>

<ul class="product-hover-wrap">
<li class="product-link" style="width: 100%; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999999;">
<a href="singleitem/<?php echo $id; ?>/itemv/">VIEW</a>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
 </li>
<?php
}
echo $results;  
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not passing the page numbers`? Where the `page` has a correct value and where it doesn't?. Do you get to `success` callback? If you'll put `console.log(data)` inside it what is the output?

Comment: In your AJAX `success`, what does `data` look like? The `center` element is considered obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. Same goes for `font`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font.

Comment: It appears `data` returns a `list-item` aka `<li>` and hidden `inputs`, but they are wrapped in a `div#comboB `. A `list-item` must be wrapped in an `ul`, `ul` or `menu`.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your PHP you try to get the param "textboxSearch" but you don't send it in your Ajax call. 
Your data in your Ajax call should be like:

```js
data: {page: page,
       textboxSearch: $("#book").val()},
```

The full code should be something like this.

### index.php

```php
<?php

echo <<<HTML
<form name="keyup">
    <input value="" type="text" id="book" >
</form>

<div id="comboB" class="comboB products-container" style="z-index: -999999999999999;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#book').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.comboB').load('search.php ', {action: 'onkeyup',  textboxSearch: $(this).val()
},
{action: 'onkeydown',  textboxSearch: $(this).val()}, function(response) {
        console.log('Response of sample: ' + response + ' if you need');
});

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        var total_pages = parseInt($("#total_pages").val());
        var page = parseInt($("#page").val())+1;
        if(page <= total_pages) {
        load_more_data(page, total_pages);
        } 
    }
});

function load_more_data(page, total_pages) {
$("#total_pages, #page").remove(); 
$.ajax({
url: 'search.php',
type: "POST",
data: {page: page,
       textboxSearch: $("#book").val()},
beforeSend: function(){
    $(".loader").show();
},
complete: function(){
$('.loader').hide();
    if(page == total_pages) {
    $(".loader").html('<hr style="border: 2px black solid;"><h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i> Total Results ( <font color="red">' + <?php echo $ttrows; // Category ID ?> + '</font> ) - No More Results <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i></h2><hr style="border: 2px black solid;">').show();
    }
},
success: function(data){
    $(".comboB").append(data);
},
error: function(){
$(".loader").html("No data found!");
}
});
}
</script>
HTML;
?>
```

Also your "sample.php" should be named as "search.php", because in your ajax call your url is `url: 'search.php'`.

I hope to help you.

Comment: What's the problem now? The same ?